# Is this "Ghost Detector App" photographing paranormal phenomena?

Tags: ghosts

I have [Ghost Detector Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/ghost-detector-pro-free-evp/id398023035?mt=8) on my iPhone.

It claims there is a ghost detected, and it can take a photo.

When a photo is taken, there are always strange, orbs, globs, and things in it.

I've experimented with dust and I've made orb-like things. My questions are, how does the detector know there is this anomaly floating around, and what are these things in the photos?

Comment: 99.9999999% it's a total scam and the globs are generated in software

Comment: How do you define "paranormal?"  Is a photo filter that ads glowing orbs normal, or "paranormal"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking how a piece of software works.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think you missed a few 9s in there :)

Comment: Add a photo, that might help. Not a very fit question for this site though.

Answer (score 13):

The App description includes this disclaimer: *["This application is intended for novelty purposes only."](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/ghost-detector-pro-free-evp/id398023035?mt=8)* so it is clearly not intended to be taken seriously.

> **how does the detector know there is this anomaly floating around**

There's no evidence to suggest anything other than a [pseudo-random number generator (PRNG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

> **what are these things in the photos?**

Other Purple Penguin apps include "Zombie My Face". You should not conclude that zombies are present.